# Is there any performance difference between different linq usage ordering?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

`IEnumerable<Element>.Cast<SomeClass>().FirstOrDefault();`

vs

`IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault().Cast<SomeClass>();`

The reason why I ask is, I see a lot of examples online using it in the first manner.
However, is the second linq sequence better performance-wise, since it avoids casting all Elements in the IEnumerable first? Or maybe the first one is safer? Or are they actually doing exactly the same backstage?

Comment: Also second one will not compile. You will need to write `(object)IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault()`. Or `IEnumerable<Element>.Take(1).Cast<SomeClass>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Does hugeness even matter? It's deferred execution.

Comment: `(SomeClass)(IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault())` is the correct code

Comment: @AluanHaddad that has the same issue as `IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault().Cast<SomeClass>();` that I explained

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True, but `IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault().Cast<SomeClass>()` is incorrect unless `Element` is an `IEnumerable<Something>`. The reason I mention my version is that there's no reason to perform the cast because it's not a filter but just an arbitrary cast of the first element

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "The first one will construct `SomeClass` with the default constructor if IEnumerable<Element> is empty" is correct only if `SomeClass` is a value type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable<Element>.Cast<SomeClass>().FirstOrDefault();` is *probably* want you want, but the answer has nothing to do with performance.

Unless `Element` is `IEnumerable`, it doesn't make sense to use `Cast()` on the result of `FirstOrDefault()`, and will result in a compile error.

Assuming you meant `(SomeClass)(IEnumerable<Element>.FirstOrDefault());` for your second case, this is also problematic because if `IEnumerable<Element>` is empty, then `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if `Element` is a reference type, or default construct `Element` if it's a value type. It would be preferable to default construct `SomeClass` in the event that `IEnumerable<Element>` is empty and `SomeClass` is a value type, rather than attempting to cast from `Element` to `SomeClass`.

`IEnumerable<Element>.Cast<SomeClass>().FirstOrDefault();` will only ever perform a maximum of one cast from `Element` to `SomeClass` because LINQ chains are lazily enumerated.

Comment: "then FirstOrDefault() will default construct a `Element`" - if `Element` is a reference type - no it will not construct it.

Comment: @GuruStron don't we still typically refer to that reference type behavior as constructing or at least producing a default value which just happens to be `null`

Comment: @GuruStron sorry you're right. It's been a while since I've worked on C#, I've got C++ semantics stuck in my head.

Comment: Nice! I would say deferred and not lazy because those aren't equal in all contexts. Basically, you don't have to worry about `Cast` or `Select`, etc. enumerating the entire collection before you get to the subsequent call (`Where`, etc) because the elements are yielded.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Personally never heard term "construct(ed)" to be used in regards of default value for reference types. Also `null`'s usually don't have problems with downcasting.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils "deferred" and "lazy" are synonyms, and are both frequently (and correctly) used to describe LINQ. I'm not sure where you've heard they're "not equal in all contexts".

Comment: @GuruStron thank you. That's fair, especially given that nullable reference types are in the language now. But if you read the .NET docs, they tend to speak in such terms. I appreciate your input as I really just wanted to know the conventional way of putting it in case I was getting it wrong and confusing people

Comment: You're correct but it's commonly confused with lazy *loading* while using implementations of the LINQ interface (e.g.: ORMs). I've never heard of deferred loading used in that context.